# How to throw custom error for KafkaJS client when initialization fails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am using the following code to initialize the Kafka client:

```
this.kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: <my_client_ID>,
  brokers: [
    `${process.env.KAFKA_BROKER_1}`,
    `${process.env.KAFKA_BROKER_2}`,
    `${process.env.KAFKA_BROKER_3}`,
  ],
  retry: {
    initialRetryTime: 3000,
    retries: 3,
  },

});
```

Now if there's an issue with connecting to the brokers it will throw errors like this:

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-19T04:21:08.143Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"<broker_1>","clientId":"<my_client_id"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-19T04:21:08.144Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection timeout","retryCount":0,"retryTime":299}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-19T04:21:08.143Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"<broker_2>","clientId":"<my_client_id"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-19T04:21:09.447Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection timeout","retryCount":1,"retryTime":564}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-19T04:21:08.143Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"<broker_3>","clientId":"<my_client_id"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2022-10-19T04:21:11.014Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Connection timeout","retryCount":2,"retryTime":1008}
```

Now, I want to change the log message here OR add a custom message after this happens. I am thinking of wrapping it in a try-catch block but for some reason it's not throwing the exception. So:

1. Is there a way to change this out of the box log to a custom log?
2. How can I add a custom long if (1) is not possible if the Kafka client fails to initialize?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to add custom logs to handle certain error scenarios.

[Kafkajs](https://kafka.js.org/) provides a way to create our own custom logs and use them instead of default ones.

[here](https://kafka.js.org/docs/1.16.0/custom-logger) is the reference for the same. You can check your version of kafkajs to avoid compatibility issues. Have added an example below.

```js
{
        level: 4,
        label: 'INFO', // NOTHING, ERROR, WARN, INFO, or DEBUG
        timestamp: '2017-12-29T13:39:54.575Z',
        logger: 'kafkajs',
        message: 'Started',
        // ... any other extra key provided to the log function
    }
```

```js
const { logLevel } = require('kafkajs')
const winston = require('winston')
const toWinstonLogLevel = level => switch(level) {
    case logLevel.ERROR:
    case logLevel.NOTHING:
        return 'error'
    case logLevel.WARN:
        return 'warn'
    case logLevel.INFO:
        return 'info'
    case logLevel.DEBUG:
        return 'debug'
}

const WinstonLogCreator = logLevel => {
    const logger = winston.createLogger({
        level: toWinstonLogLevel(logLevel),
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console(),
            new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'myapp.log' })
        ]
    })

    return ({ namespace, level, label, log }) => {
        const { message, ...extra } = log
        logger.log({
            level: toWinstonLogLevel(level),
            message,
            extra,
        })
    }
}

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'my-app',
    brokers: ['kafka1:9092', 'kafka2:9092'],
    logLevel: logLevel.ERROR,
    logCreator: WinstonLogCreator
})
```

Thanks.